# Skype doesn't launch

Tags: skype

When I installed Skype that week, skype worked great only that you couldn't launch it twice during a session, if I closed skype, to re-open I had to restart my computer, after a few days Skype blacked out at random moment a few day later when I launched skype it told me not enough space or something similar, now it doesn't launch anymore. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

@Braiam: If I write `df -h` it telles me :

```
df: `/root/.gvfs': Permission denied
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       143G   44G   92G  33% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           772M  940K  771M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  428K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            1.9G   38M  1.9G   2% /tmp/guest-S30red
```

@Braiam2: If I type what you said it shows me:

```
19441 ?        Sl     1:40 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/software-center /home/victor     /Downloads/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
22560 pts/1    R+     0:00 grep --color=auto skype
26980 ?        Sl     4:35 skype
```

To Briaiam's answer:

```
rm -r ~/.skype ~/.config/skype
rm: cannot remove /home/victor/.skype': No such file or directory 
rm: cannot remove /home/victor/.config/skype': No such file or directory
```

To Braiam's answer(purge):
The 2 first lines of your code don't show any error but the last one does, it will show me:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done 
>   E: Unable to locate package skype

Comment: I had problems with Skype startup conflicting with some other programs and have been successful with delaying its startup, like this in my startup applicatons: 

bash -c "sleep 30 && skype"

This delays Skype startup for 30 seconds, and essentially allows other stuff to startup first...

Comment: @Kendor How is that helpful here?

Comment: Just find the launcher file in `/usr/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/` -  it may be called `skype.desktop`. Search it for the `Exec=` line, and then run the result in terminal. From memory, should be `skype`, but can sometimes be `skype-wrapper`. For running single instances of Skype, I have found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1851256) and [this](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Ubuntu-11-04-Unity-Launcher-and-Multiple-Instances-of-Skype/td-p/181856).

Comment: You could search for skype in apt-cache - `sudo apt-cache search skype`.

Answer (score 2):

Skype is already running in the background. That's why whatever you do you can't start it. You must kill it (sadly, not literally):

```
pkill skype
```

Then try to run skype again, if still fails do the following:

```
pkill skype
rm -r ~/.Skype
```

Then try to start skype again. The above command should have cleared any weirdness skype has.

If things comes to worse, then lets purge it:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge skype
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository "http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: None of the command work. The second one shows me :( rm: cannot remove `/home/victor/.skype': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/home/victor/.config/skype': No such file or directory)

Comment: @Victor close the software center and try the commands again.

Comment: @Victor try again.

Comment: I've done what you said, now when I click on skype it doesn't do anything. So I typed in the terminal " sudo skype" and it opens it BUT when I try to log in they say "can't log in because I'm already logged in, on this computer" so I wrote on the terminal "pkill skype" and then "sudo skype" but it still shows me that message 0.O

Comment: @Victor do not use ever `sudo` with `skype`. skype was not meant to be used with `sudo`. Your problem is that skype is running somewhere and you don't see it. Run `rm -r ~/.Skype` and try again.

Comment: omg I feel like suiciding. I will try wilf's method even if I'm almost sure it won't work :'(